# Any built in hash method in C++?

Tags: c++, function, hash

I was looking for md5 for C++, and I realize md5 is not built in (even though there are a lot of very good libraries to support the md5 function). Then, I realized I don't actually need md5, any hashing method will do. Thus, I was wondering if C++ has such functions? I mean, built-in hashing functions?

While I was researching for C++, I saw Java, PHP, and some other programming languages support md5. For example, in PHP, you just need to call: `md5("your string");`.

A simple hash function will do. (If possible, please include some simple code on how to use it.)

Comment: How about crc32? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302914/crc32-c-or-c-implementation

Comment: Asking for a "hash method" is pretty vague. Do you need a cryptographic hash? Or are you just trying to index a collection? Do you need resistance to algorithmic complexity attacks? Etcetera.

Answer (score 11):

This is simple. With C++11 you get a

```
hash<string>
```

*functor* which you can use like this (untested, but gives you the idea):

```
hash<string> h;
const size_t value = h("mystring");
```

If you don't have C++11, take a look at boost, maybe `boost::tr1::hash_map`. They probably provide a string-hashing function, too.

For very simple cases you can start with something along these lines:

```
size_t h = 0
for(int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i)
    h = h*31 + s[i];
return h;
```

To take up the comment below. To prevent short strings from clustering you may want to initialize `h` differently. Maybe you can use the length for that (but that is just my first idea, unproven):

```
size_t h = numeric_limits::max<size_t>() / (s.length()+1); // +1: no div-by-0
...
```

This should not be worse then before, but still far from perfect.

Comment: Note that this hash function tends to cluster when there are a large number of very short strings.  (Not a frequent occurrence, and it's fairly good in most cases.)

Comment: @JamesKanze what do you think of my idea about the initialization if h?

Comment: It's not the initialization that causes the clustering, but the small multiplier.  I usually use `127`, but an even larger prime might be in order today.  (Obviously, you shouldn't use `0` for initialization if you can have `'\0'` bytes in the string; strings of all `'\0'` bytes will hash to the same value, regardless of length.  But again, this isn't usually an issue.)

Answer (score 8):

It depends which version of C++ you have... and what kind of hashing function you are looking for.

C++03 does not have any hashing container, and thus no need for hashing. A number of compilers have been proposing custom headers though. Otherwise Boost.Functional.Hash may help.

C++0x has the `unordered_` family of containers, and thus a `std::hash` predicate, which already works for C++ standard types (built-in types and `std::string`, at least).

However, this is a simple hash, good enough for hash maps, **not for security**.

If you are looking for cryptographic hash, then the issue is completely different (and md5 is loosy), and you'll need a library for (for example) a SHA-2 hash.

If you are looking for speed, check out [CityHash](http://code.google.com/p/cityhash/) and [MurmurHash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash). Both have restrictions, but they are heavily optimized.

Comment: So you can add `hash<MyType>` specializations?

Comment: @xtofl: yes, it is meant to be used as the current `std::less`, but for hash maps. Or you can simply pass a custom predicate to a given hash map.

Answer (score 4):

How about using boost, [Boost.Functional/Hash](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/hash.html)