# Fast C implementation of CRC32 for char arrays

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CRC32 C or C++ implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302914/crc32-c-or-c-implementation)

Where can I find a CRC32 implementation for strings?

Comment: Why would it be different than for any other data?

Comment: On the internet? By Googling?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302914/crc32-c-or-c-implementation

Comment: @Mat, What is this *internet* that you speak of?

Answer (score 1):

There are many specifications for CRC32 depending on the polynomial (magic numbers).  First thing to do is find out which specific CRC32 you need.  Then generate the CRC32 table using a code generator.

Comment: There are several CRC32 variants. This is because there are three configuration factors, Reflected input (simply bit reversed), Reflected output (again the output of the CRC32 bit reversed) and the seed or start value which is generally either 0xFFFFFFFF or 0x00000000. That gives eight variants already!