# How to calculate a CRC-32 from 16-bit data?

Tags: c, crc32

How would I (in C/C++) calculate the CRC32 from the following 16-bit data?

The data is:

0x0000,
0x083A,
0x0000,
0xFFF7,
0x0000,
0xFFFE,
0x0000,
0x0001,
0x5001,
0x0003,
0xE00A,
0x0015,
0xC009,
0x0320,
0x8A54

I assume the CRC32 = 0xB6C815B4 according to the following (from the ADIS16495 datasheet):

[image]

I managed to get the correct CRC32 online ([Link to online CRC page](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html)).

I swapped the byte order of the 8-bit pairs.

But I don't know how to implement it in C. There is at least a pre-calculated lookup table on the page.

[image: Screen dump of CRC32 calculation]

Comment: You could use the library mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302914/crc32-c-or-c-implementation

Comment: What the data represents is irrelevant, any CRC function should just treat the data as a series of bytes.

Comment: By using bitwise XOR. This isn't the place to ask for the complete code with no attempts shown. But you shouldn't need to roll out this code manually either, look for a reliable implementation on the internet instead.

Comment: Posting text as _text_ is more useful and considerate rather than as a _picture_.

Comment: The only variable here is the byte order, and you only have two choices.  Use the example you have and try it one way and the other until you get the expected value.

Comment: You need to know the [CRC polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Polynomial_representations_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks), which is not shown in that image.

Comment: You will not need to swap the byte order if your target is little-endian (for example a PC).  There are any number of CRC-32 implementations available.  Start with one of those and ask a _specific_ question if you have difficulties.

Comment: @user3386109 : Unless explicitly stated otherwise, you can normally assume thet "CRC-32" refers to the standard CRC-32-IEEE polynomial, as used to HDLC, Ethernet etc.

Comment: I always use *A painless guide to crc error detection algorithms* @ http://www.ross.net/crc/crcpaper.html It includes C source code.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the correct CRC32 online ([Link to online CRC page](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html)).

I swapped the byte order of the 8-bit pairs.

[Screen dump of CRC32 calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHSxu.png)

And also managed to solve the C implementation (don't know if this is the optimal solution):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint16_t data[15] = {
    0x0000, 0x083A, 0x0000, 0xFFF7, 0x0000, 0xFFFE, 0x0000, 0x0001, 0x5001, 0x0003, 0xE00A, 0x0015, 0xC009, 0x0320, 0x8A54
};

const uint32_t crcTable[] = {
0x00000000, 0x04C11DB7, 0x09823B6E, 0x0D4326D9, 0x130476DC, 0x17C56B6B, 0x1A864DB2, 0x1E475005, 
0x2608EDB8, 0x22C9F00F, 0x2F8AD6D6, 0x2B4BCB61, 0x350C9B64, 0x31CD86D3, 0x3C8EA00A, 0x384FBDBD, 
0x4C11DB70, 0x48D0C6C7, 0x4593E01E, 0x4152FDA9, 0x5F15ADAC, 0x5BD4B01B, 0x569796C2, 0x52568B75, 
0x6A1936C8, 0x6ED82B7F, 0x639B0DA6, 0x675A1011, 0x791D4014, 0x7DDC5DA3, 0x709F7B7A, 0x745E66CD, 
0x9823B6E0, 0x9CE2AB57, 0x91A18D8E, 0x95609039, 0x8B27C03C, 0x8FE6DD8B, 0x82A5FB52, 0x8664E6E5, 
0xBE2B5B58, 0xBAEA46EF, 0xB7A96036, 0xB3687D81, 0xAD2F2D84, 0xA9EE3033, 0xA4AD16EA, 0xA06C0B5D, 
0xD4326D90, 0xD0F37027, 0xDDB056FE, 0xD9714B49, 0xC7361B4C, 0xC3F706FB, 0xCEB42022, 0xCA753D95, 
0xF23A8028, 0xF6FB9D9F, 0xFBB8BB46, 0xFF79A6F1, 0xE13EF6F4, 0xE5FFEB43, 0xE8BCCD9A, 0xEC7DD02D, 
0x34867077, 0x30476DC0, 0x3D044B19, 0x39C556AE, 0x278206AB, 0x23431B1C, 0x2E003DC5, 0x2AC12072, 
0x128E9DCF, 0x164F8078, 0x1B0CA6A1, 0x1FCDBB16, 0x018AEB13, 0x054BF6A4, 0x0808D07D, 0x0CC9CDCA, 
0x7897AB07, 0x7C56B6B0, 0x71159069, 0x75D48DDE, 0x6B93DDDB, 0x6F52C06C, 0x6211E6B5, 0x66D0FB02, 
0x5E9F46BF, 0x5A5E5B08, 0x571D7DD1, 0x53DC6066, 0x4D9B3063, 0x495A2DD4, 0x44190B0D, 0x40D816BA, 
0xACA5C697, 0xA864DB20, 0xA527FDF9, 0xA1E6E04E, 0xBFA1B04B, 0xBB60ADFC, 0xB6238B25, 0xB2E29692, 
0x8AAD2B2F, 0x8E6C3698, 0x832F1041, 0x87EE0DF6, 0x99A95DF3, 0x9D684044, 0x902B669D, 0x94EA7B2A, 
0xE0B41DE7, 0xE4750050, 0xE9362689, 0xEDF73B3E, 0xF3B06B3B, 0xF771768C, 0xFA325055, 0xFEF34DE2, 
0xC6BCF05F, 0xC27DEDE8, 0xCF3ECB31, 0xCBFFD686, 0xD5B88683, 0xD1799B34, 0xDC3ABDED, 0xD8FBA05A, 
0x690CE0EE, 0x6DCDFD59, 0x608EDB80, 0x644FC637, 0x7A089632, 0x7EC98B85, 0x738AAD5C, 0x774BB0EB, 
0x4F040D56, 0x4BC510E1, 0x46863638, 0x42472B8F, 0x5C007B8A, 0x58C1663D, 0x558240E4, 0x51435D53, 
0x251D3B9E, 0x21DC2629, 0x2C9F00F0, 0x285E1D47, 0x36194D42, 0x32D850F5, 0x3F9B762C, 0x3B5A6B9B, 
0x0315D626, 0x07D4CB91, 0x0A97ED48, 0x0E56F0FF, 0x1011A0FA, 0x14D0BD4D, 0x19939B94, 0x1D528623, 
0xF12F560E, 0xF5EE4BB9, 0xF8AD6D60, 0xFC6C70D7, 0xE22B20D2, 0xE6EA3D65, 0xEBA91BBC, 0xEF68060B, 
0xD727BBB6, 0xD3E6A601, 0xDEA580D8, 0xDA649D6F, 0xC423CD6A, 0xC0E2D0DD, 0xCDA1F604, 0xC960EBB3, 
0xBD3E8D7E, 0xB9FF90C9, 0xB4BCB610, 0xB07DABA7, 0xAE3AFBA2, 0xAAFBE615, 0xA7B8C0CC, 0xA379DD7B, 
0x9B3660C6, 0x9FF77D71, 0x92B45BA8, 0x9675461F, 0x8832161A, 0x8CF30BAD, 0x81B02D74, 0x857130C3, 
0x5D8A9099, 0x594B8D2E, 0x5408ABF7, 0x50C9B640, 0x4E8EE645, 0x4A4FFBF2, 0x470CDD2B, 0x43CDC09C, 
0x7B827D21, 0x7F436096, 0x7200464F, 0x76C15BF8, 0x68860BFD, 0x6C47164A, 0x61043093, 0x65C52D24, 
0x119B4BE9, 0x155A565E, 0x18197087, 0x1CD86D30, 0x029F3D35, 0x065E2082, 0x0B1D065B, 0x0FDC1BEC, 
0x3793A651, 0x3352BBE6, 0x3E119D3F, 0x3AD08088, 0x2497D08D, 0x2056CD3A, 0x2D15EBE3, 0x29D4F654, 
0xC5A92679, 0xC1683BCE, 0xCC2B1D17, 0xC8EA00A0, 0xD6AD50A5, 0xD26C4D12, 0xDF2F6BCB, 0xDBEE767C, 
0xE3A1CBC1, 0xE760D676, 0xEA23F0AF, 0xEEE2ED18, 0xF0A5BD1D, 0xF464A0AA, 0xF9278673, 0xFDE69BC4, 
0x89B8FD09, 0x8D79E0BE, 0x803AC667, 0x84FBDBD0, 0x9ABC8BD5, 0x9E7D9662, 0x933EB0BB, 0x97FFAD0C, 
0xAFB010B1, 0xAB710D06, 0xA6322BDF, 0xA2F33668, 0xBCB4666D, 0xB8757BDA, 0xB5365D03, 0xB1F740B4 
};

uint8_t reflect8(uint8_t b) {
    uint8_t from = 0x01;
    uint8_t to = 0x80;
    uint8_t r = 0;
    while(to)
    {
        if(b & from) r |= to;
        from <<= 1;
        to >>= 1;
    }
    return r;
}

uint32_t reflect32(uint32_t b) {
    uint32_t from = 0x00000001;
    uint32_t to = 0x80000000;
    uint32_t r = 0;
    while(to)
    {
        if(b & from) r |= to;
        from <<= 1;
        to >>= 1;
    }
    return r;
}

uint32_t
crc32 (const uint16_t *buf, size_t size)
{
  uint32_t crc;

  crc = 0xFFFFFFFF; /* CRC is set to specified initial value */
  while (size--)
  {
    /* Take LSB */

    uint8_t b = reflect8(*buf); /* Reflect input byte */

    /* XOR-in next input byte into MSB of crc and get this MSB, that's our new intermediate divident */
    uint8_t pos = (uint8_t)((crc ^ (b << 24)) >> 24);

    /* Shift out the MSB used for division per lookuptable and XOR with the remainder */
    crc = (crc << 8) ^ crcTable[pos];

    /* Take MSB */

    b = reflect8(*buf >> 8); /* Reflect input byte */
    buf++;

    /* XOR-in next input byte into MSB of crc and get this MSB, that's our new intermediate divident */
    pos = (uint8_t)((crc ^ (b << 24)) >> 24);

    /* Shift out the MSB used for division per lookuptable and XOR with the remainder */
    crc = (crc << 8) ^ crcTable[pos];
  }
  /* Reflect result crc */
  crc = reflect32(crc);
  /* Xor the crc value with specified final XOR value before returning */
  return crc ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
}


int
main ()
{
  uint32_t crc = crc32(data, 15);
  printf("CRC = 0x%" PRIx32 "\n", crc);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is a solution, but for such small data payloads, the look-up table method is probably unnecessary - a lot of memory used for an unnecessary performance improvement.  Moreover there are smarter ways of handling MSB/LSB without duplicating the code, and the `reflect` functions can be avoided too.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the actual CRC-32 calculation has been dome many times, and made freely available from many sources. [Here](http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/crc.c.txt) for example are several implementations to choose from, all share the same interface of the form:

```
unsigned int crc32(unsigned char *message);
```

This is not immediately suited to your needs as it assumes that `message` is a null-terminated text string rather than binary data, it also assumes a 32-bit `int`.  So you need to remove those assumptions and explicitly pass the length.  To avoid casting, you could make the data a `void*`:

```
uint32_t crc32( void* data, size_t length ) ;
```

Since you entered each value in low-byte/high-byte order in your test, then for a little-endian platform (such as an x86 PC or most ARM devices), then you do not need to swap the byte order

```
uint32_t crc = crc32( adis16495_data, sizeof(adis16495_data) ) ;
```

So adapting the second example at the link above (because it is the shortest, not because it is necessarily the best - in this case I doubt it matters), and cleaning up the code a little:

```
uint32_t crc32( void* data, size_t length ) 
{
   uint32_t byte ;
   uint32_t mask ;
   uint32_t crc = 0xFFFFFFFFu;
   uint8_t* byte_data = (uint8_t*)data ;

   for( int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
   {
      byte = byte_data[i];            // Get next byte.
      crc = crc ^ byte;
      for( int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) 
      {
         mask = -(crc & 1);
         crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (0xEDB88320u & mask);
      }
   }

   return ~crc;
}
```

If you your data was in big-endian form, then rather than laboriously swapping the byte order, the the function could be specialised, explicitly for 16 bit data:

```
uint32_t crc32_16bit( uint16_t* data, size_t count ) 
{
   uint32_t byte ;
   uint32_t mask ;
   uint32_t crc = 0xFFFFFFFFu;
   size_t length = count * 2 ;

   for( int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
   {
      // Get next byte, LSB on even i, MSB on odd i
      byte = (i & 1) == 0) ? data[i] & 0x00FF : 
                             data[i] >> 8 ; 
      crc = crc ^ byte ;
      for( int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) 
      {
         mask = -(crc & 1);
         crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (0xEDB88320u & mask);
      }
   }

   return ~crc;
}
```

In this, the `count` argument is the number of 16 bit words, not the byte length as before, so it might be called:

```
uint32_t crc = crc32( adis16495_data, sizeof(adis16495_data) / sizeof(uint16_t) ) ;
```

for example.